# ArcGIS: Fetching raster tiles that are custom desined

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, tiles, design

Is it possible to fetch tiles as bitmaps, that were designed in a map builder by ArcGIS, like it can be done in Mapbox?

Comment: Probably, though providing a graphic to show your meaning would improve the Question.

Answer (score 0):

If the service is a tiled service, you can certainly download individual tiles. For example, for [this service](https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSHydroCached/MapServer), you can use this url:
https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSHydroCached/MapServer/tile/4/4/1?blankTile=false

If the service is a dynamic map service then you can use the [export endpoint](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/export-map.htm) to get an image. For example, for [this service](https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer), you can use this url:
https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/export?bbox=-113.027344%2C+29.075375%2C-74.531250%2C+46.920255&bboxSR=4324&f=image

(change `f=image` to `f=html` to get a helpful form to help you construct the URL, as an additional helper on top of the REST documentation)